# Unable to understand working of np.isclose()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For the following input:

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

b= np.array([1.0, 1.0, -2.234])
print(np.isclose(np.transpose(a), b))
```

Output:

```
$ python temp.py 
--> [[False  True False]
    [False  True False]
    [False False False]]
```

And for following input:

```
print(np.isclose(a, b))
```

Output:

```
$ python temp.py 
--> [[False False False]
    [ True  True  True]
    [False False False]]
```

I am unable to understand why `np.isclose()` is unable to match column element-wise but is able to do it correctly for rows. I think there is something wrong with my understanding.

My intention is to find index of matching column. To achieve this I would be further using `.all(axis=)` with `np.where()`. But before this I want to understand the behaviour of `np.isclose()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that `numpy` automatically ["broadcasts"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the lower-dimensional array to match the shape of the higher-dimensional array.

In this concrete instance the `b` array gets broadcasted into a matrix where each row is a copy of the original array `b`. You can check the shape it gets broadcasted to ahead of time by calling `np.broadcast_to(b, a.shape)`.

```py
a= np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

b= np.array([1.0, 1.0, -2.234])
print(np.isclose(np.transpose(a), b))
```

`np.isclose(np.transpose(a), b)` resolves to

```py
np.isclose([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, -2.234, 0.0]],

           [[1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234]])

--> [[False  True False]
     [False  True False]
     [False False False]]
```

And `np.isclose(a, b)` resolves to

```py
np.isclose([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],

           [[1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234]])

--> [[False False False]
     [ True  True  True]
     [False False False]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your transposed array `a` and `b`:

```
[[ 0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -2.234  0.   ]]

[ 1.     1.    -2.234]
```

What `np.isclose` is doing is literally comparing (within a given tolerance) each element in each row of `a` with each element in `b` based on broadcasting, which results in the output:

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

If you want to compare the arrays "column-wise", you should explicitly add an additional dimension to `b`. Arrays `a` and `b` would then look like this:

```
[[ 0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -2.234  0.   ]]

[[ 1.   ]
 [ 1.   ]
 [-2.234]]
```

Then you can see if they are equal:

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0, -2.234],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

b = np.array([1.0, 1.0, -2.234])
a = np.transpose(a)
b = np.expand_dims(b , axis=-1)
print(np.isclose(a, b))
```

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [False  True False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) just checks that the values are close enough that you can consider them equal with a given threshold

By doing:

```
np.isclose(np.transpose(a), b)
```

you compare each column of a.T with each column of b.
The first column `[0,0,0]` is not close (i.e. almost equal) to `1`. For the second column `[1,1,-2.234]`, the first 2 values are equal to `1`. For the last column `[0,0,0]`, nothing matches `-2.234`.

```
[[False  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```